# Is there an open source license that forces derivative work to attribution?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I'm pretty much looking for something similar to the creative commons cc-by-sa license, but they don't recommend to use it for code. Is there something that includes attribution? The popular ones (GPL, APL, EPL, BSD, MIT, ...) don't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer mostly depends on what kind of attribution you want. All popular licenses require copyright notices to be preserved, which means in practice that the author is acknowledged in the source code. If you want something like old BSD advertisement clause but with share-alike, I am not familiar with a license like that. Share-alike (also called copyleft) guarantees access to the source code, so attributions made there are more effective than in BSD-style licenses, where binary-only derivatives are permitted.

Modifying the GPL should follow [the recommendation of the FSF](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#ModifyGPL), otherwise several distributors, including Debian, would consider your work undistributable. Supplementing the GPL with additional permissions is not subject to this rule.

Comment: Would this include a copyright notice in a README file or on a website? My fear is that someone takes our software, renames it and sells it, pretending it was theirs.

Comment: It is recommended that copyright notices is included in every source file. You may also include them in a README. Derived works must preserve these. Having notices in every file helps in case a derived work includes only a couple of files. I just checked that also binary copies must include copyright notices, however, the preparer of a derived work can alter the form of their presentation. Nevertheless, "Copyright Original Author" has to be in every copy in a some prominent form. You cannot require anyone to include notices on a website, according to the GPL.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache license allows you to include a NOTICE file that all derivative works must include (but it's not copyleft, like the cc-by-sa). That could serve as your attribution.

If you want the derivative works to be distributed under the same license as the original, you can always modify your favorite copyleft license (GPL for most people) to require attribution, or just write your own license from scratch (look at the MIT or BSD licenses--they're both only a few paragraphs, and they get the job done).

Comment: If modifying a license be careful as as far as I know you can't use the same name for what is essentially your own license. You can't add a clause like "If we ever meet you have to sing me a song." to GPL and still call it GPL. I think you can't even call it Singing GPL. But I'm not a lawyer so I could have this whole thing wrong.

Comment: Do I have to modify the license itself? Can I not do something like: "This is licensed under the GPL. If you distribute it, you have to include the following notice: ..."?

Comment: @forneo: Absolutely not. The GPL forbids additional restrictions, so including them is the kind of inconsistent license that would cause several distributors not to distribute your work. It is not certain if the invalidity of the license would be upheld in court, but Debian, among others, will not take the risk. It is not recommended to cause legal uncertainty.